Issues with executing WORLD DATABASE .sql database on mysql
I have issues executing a .sql database. (world data base)enter image description here
I imported world database. some of the files could not be executed successfully. so I am unable to create a database and work on an assignment.

Have you followed the instructions included with the errors? Either add USE name_of_your_db; to the top of the file to be imported, or select the db in Workbench before executing the batch.

Where did you get the world database?

From my instructor. I am a beginner

welcome to stackoverflow! please include the errors you receive, the commands you use, and try to add more detail to what your specific issue is.
